# Designer Load Failures

Tags: c#

The **designer** fails to load in the `.xaml` window of the **WPF application** in **Visual Studio**. I have tried tp debug the issue but still no clue on why the designer of every window fails to load though the code is working fine and application is created while running the build of the solution.

I have provided the error image below. Please help me understand the error and resolve the issue. Thanks!

[image: Error- unhandled exception]

Comment: Does the designer also crash if you create and open a new, empty WPF window?

Comment: Yes, the designer crashes while loading a new empty window.

Comment: After opening up project go to menu File : SAVE ALL and select a folder that you have permission to write.

Comment: That sounds like a broken Visual Studio installation. A reinstall might fix it.